# ReactJS with graphql CORS Issue with django backend

Tags: reactjs, django, graphql, apollo-client

I have running `django` backend on `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and I want to request it with `reactjs` frontend.

As you can see below, I can see the successful response in the `Insomnia` app.

[image]

But, When I want a request with reactjs frontend, I get a `CORS` ERROR.

I check the request in the inspect networks and I saw a similar request payload with insomnia.

[image]

Comment: try `django-cors-headers` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. install `django-cors-headers`:
   `pip install django-cors-headers`
2. Add `corsheaders` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]
```

3. Add `CorsMiddleware` to your middlewares in `settings.py`:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...,
]
```

4. Now you can set your allowed origins in `settings.py` like this:

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
]
```

More info in this [link](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers).